# How to read blob from excel sheet in extjs

Tags: javascript, java, extjs5

I have a excel sheet which contains multiple columns with data along with a column which contains file paths. When I upload it to `extjs` grid, I want to read blob data based on the file path column before it's submitted to a database. I don't have a form, I need to get data when clicking on a submit button from the grid. How can we read local system data from an excel sheet. I have tried to read  the image at the backed (using java spring) but it's reading as if client and server both exits in single system. I want to read the blob from client side. How can I do it in java. Please give some suggestion.

[image: PFA]

Answer (score 0):

private static void GetShapePosition(HttpServletRequest request) {

```
  try {
   InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("D:/SVN_PROJECTS/WorkDevServer/EnrollSample.xls");
   Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
   HSSFSheet sheet = (HSSFSheet)wb.getSheetAt(0);
   HashMap<String,byte[]> hashMap = new HashMap<String,byte[]>();
   HSSFPatriarch dravingPatriarch = sheet.getDrawingPatriarch();

   java.util.List<HSSFShape> shapes = dravingPatriarch.getChildren();

   for (HSSFShape shape : shapes) {
    if (shape instanceof HSSFPicture) {
     HSSFPicture hssfPicture = (HSSFPicture)shape;
     int picIndex = hssfPicture.getPictureIndex();
     String filename = hssfPicture.getFileName();
     HSSFPictureData hssfPictureData =  hssfPicture.getPictureData();
     byte[] b = hssfPictureData.getData();
     String s= hssfPictureData.getMimeType();
     HSSFClientAnchor hca =  hssfPicture.getPreferredSize();
     System.out.println("      row : -> "+(hca.getRow1())+"       column : -> "+(hca.getCol1()) );
     hashMap.put(String.valueOf((hca.getRow1()))+String.valueOf((hca.getCol1())),b);
    }
  }

  request.getSession().setAttribute("ImghashMap", hashMap);

  } catch (Exception e ) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

}

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: getDrawingPatriarch() will give HSSFPatriarch object from that we can List the all image in excel sheet with the help of getChildren() method. from that you can get details of image like position and byte, imagename, mimeType